# Поддержка кириллицы в С

Tags: c, visual-studio, локализация

Как сделать в компиляторе поддержку русского языка в С?

Эквивалент в C++: `setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"rus");`

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     int main(void) { 
     printf("Привeт\n"); 
     return 0; }
```

Comment: Что именно подразумевается под поддержкой русского языка?

Comment: Что бы вместо непонятных символов компилятор отображал нормальные буквы

Comment: Где именно? В выводе сообщений об ошибках в студии?

Comment: Компилятор отображал — вы имеете в виду, в логе компиляции?

Comment: В приложении Win32 у визуаол студио

Comment: У меня в приложении Win32, собранном в студии все нормально работает. Минимальный код для воспроизведения проблемы нужен.

Comment: int main(void)
{
 
 printf("How many you have dogs?\n");/*Вивод*/
 return 0;
}

Comment: В вопрос код вставьте, и где там русские буквы не совсем ясно. Если проблема с printf - так и пишите, что printf не выводит русские буквы...

Comment: «Вивод» – это больше похоже на европейские буквы.

Comment: @NickVolynkin они в любом случае в комментарии.

Comment: Там были русские буквы вместо англ

Comment: @MaksimSuprunenko я еще раз предложу вам отредактировать вопрос, чтобы он отражал суть проблемы лучше чем сейчас и чтобы в нем был именно тот код, который вызывает проблемы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Эквивалент в C++: setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"rus");

Ну она вообще-то поддерживается в Си

```
#include <locale.h>
```

[Си](http://codepad.org/BfBtT3QE), [Си++](http://codepad.org/BfBtT3QE),